# Python set iteration time complexity

Tags: python, set, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of the following python code?

1. create set x
2. add n items in x
3. remove n items in x
4. add 1 item in x
5. iterate x m times

```
import time

def test(n, m):
    answer = 0
    start = time.time()
    x = set([i for i in range(n)])
    for i in list(x):
        x.remove(i)
    x.add(1234)
    for i in range(m):
        for j in x:
            answer+=1
    return time.time() - start

print(test(100000,100000))
```

I thought time complexity is O(m) but it takes very long time. (It took more than 10 seconds in my local environment.)
is time comlexity O(nm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set iteration takes time proportional to the size of the underlying hash table. For common usage patterns, the size of the underlying hash table is *usually* within a small constant factor of the number of elements, but when you start deleting entries, that may no longer be the case.

CPython doesn't resize sets on `remove`. It can resize on `add`, but as of the current CPython 3.11.2 implementation, `set.add` only resizes [when an added element lands in a never-previously-used table cell](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.2/Objects/setobject.c#L170-L177). If an element [lands in a cell another element has previously been deleted from](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.2/Objects/setobject.c#L162-L168), there is no resize check.

Your `x.add(1234)` lands in the cell the old `1234` element was previously deleted from, so it doesn't trigger a set resize. The removal loop doesn't trigger a resize either, since `set.remove` doesn't trigger resizes. Thus, your set's hash table is still sized for the original 100000 elements rather than the 1 remaining element when you start iterating over the set.